# Run Time Error '424' Object Required

Tags: vba, runtime-error

i'm Going to make the Copy Paste file using dialogbox, i successfully copy and paste the data to the desire sheets and cell but in the VBA Appear Run Time Error '424' Object Required message box. sorry for the mess i'm new for this. would really appreciate for the help to figure whats the problem and how to fix it :

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim dialogTitle As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim rngDestin As Range
    Dim lngRowsCopied As Long


    dialogTitle = "Navigate to and select required file."
    Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fileDialog
        .InitialFileName = "P:\Sales & Marketing\REVENUE MANAGEMENT\REPORTS"
        '.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" 'Alternative to previous line
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = dialogTitle



        If .Show = False Then
            MsgBox "File not selected to import. Process Terminated"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        strPathFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPathFile)

    Range("16:16,18:18,20:20,22:22,24:24,26:26").Select
    Range("A26").Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 12
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 14
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 16
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 17
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 19
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 20
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 22
    Range( _
        "16:16,18:18,20:20,22:22,24:24,26:26,28:28,30:30,32:32,34:34,36:36,38:38,40:40,42:42,44:44,46:46" _
        ).Select
    Range("A46").Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 26
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 27
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 28
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 29
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 30
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 31
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 32
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 33
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 34
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 35
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 36
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 37
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 38
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 39
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 40
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 41
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 42
    Range( _
        "16:16,18:18,20:20,22:22,24:24,26:26,28:28,30:30,32:32,34:34,36:36,38:38,40:40,42:42,44:44,46:46,48:48,50:50,52:52,54:54,56:56,58:58,60:60,62:62,64:64,66:66,68:68" _
        ).Select
    Range("A68").Activate
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 41
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 43
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 44
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 48
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 50
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 53
    Range( _
        "16:16,18:18,20:20,22:22,24:24,26:26,28:28,30:30,32:32,34:34,36:36,38:38,40:40,42:42,44:44,46:46,48:48,50:50,52:52,54:54,56:56,58:58,60:60,62:62,64:64,66:66,68:68,70:70,72:72,74:74" _
        ).Select
    Range("A74").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("F64").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-48
    Range("A15:P45").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Set rngDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A2").PasteSpecial


    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set fileDialog = Nothing
    Set rngRow = Nothing
    Set rngToCopy = Nothing
    Set wbSource = Nothing
    Set rngDestin = Nothing

    'MsgBox "The Data Is Imported"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to :

1. Define the range you want to paste on/from (top left cell is sufficient)
2. Then do the actual paste

So instead of :

```
Set rngDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A2").PasteSpecial
```

Do this :

```
Set rngDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A2")
rngDestin.PasteSpecial
```

---

Here is your full code with the correction and without all useless scrolls :

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim dialogTitle As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim rngDestin As Range
    Dim lngRowsCopied As Long

    dialogTitle = "Navigate to and select required file."
    Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fileDialog
        .InitialFileName = "P:\Sales & Marketing\REVENUE MANAGEMENT\REPORTS"
        '.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" 'Alternative to previous line
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = dialogTitle
        If .Show = False Then
            MsgBox "File not selected to import. Process Terminated"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        strPathFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPathFile)

    Range("16:16,18:18,20:20,22:22,24:24,26:26,28:28,30:30,32:32,34:34,36:36,38:38,40:40,42:42,44:44," & _
            "46:46,48:48,50:50,52:52,54:54,56:56,58:58,60:60,62:62,64:64,66:66,68:68,70:70,72:72,74:74" _
        ).Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Range("A15:P45").Copy

    Set rngDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Range("A2")
    rngDestin.PasteSpecial

    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set fileDialog = Nothing
    Set rngRow = Nothing
    Set rngToCopy = Nothing
    Set wbSource = Nothing
    Set rngDestin = Nothing

    'MsgBox "The Data Is Imported"

End Sub
```

Comment: you really save my life dude @R3uK ! appreciated it so much !

Comment: Glad I could help! ;) Take a minute to take the tour and see how SO works (accepting answers and voting) : http://stackoverflow.com/tour